# How to create a linear colormap with color defined at specific values with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap, norm

I would like to create a colormap that fade linearly through colors defined for specific values.
Below here is my Minimal Non Working Example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (10, 10))

values = [0., 0.8, 1., 10.]
colors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#cccccc"]
```

I have the feeling this can be solved by using `cmap` and `norm` switches when plotting with `imshow` but I could not succeed to have a smooth gradient of colors passing by defined colors at values.

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors, name="mycmap")
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(values, len(colors))

fig, axe  = plt.subplots()
cmap_ = axe.imshow(data, aspect="auto", origin="upper", cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cmap_, ax=axe)
```

Also the scale is then non linear.

[image]

How can I setup this colormap using the provided values and colors above?

Comment: `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list

Comment: @JohanC, digging a bit more in the `from_list` function I finally succeed (see my answer) to get the colormap I wanted. Anyway the code is not straightforward. Maybe you have better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the current solution I have found to solve my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
def get_colormap(values, colors, name="custom"):
    values = np.sort(np.array(values))
    values = np.interp(values, (values.min(), values.max()), (0., 1.))
    cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name, list(zip(values, colors)))
    return cmap

data = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (10, 10))
values = np.array([0., 0.8, 1., 10.])
colors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#cccccc"]
cmap_ = get_colormap(values, colors)

fig, axe  = plt.subplots()
cmap = axe.imshow(data, aspect="auto", origin="upper", cmap=cmap_)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cmap, ax=axe)
```

Not straightforward but functional. I'll keep the question unanswered to leave opportunity to best solution to come.

[image]

Comment: You can use the hex colors directly, no need to do conversions.